# How to get a type without using too many if clause?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Here is my g4 file

```
grammar sql;

singleStatement
    : CREATE TIMESERIES dataType
    ;


CREATE: 'CREATE';

TIMESERIES: 'TIMESERIES';

dataType
    : INT32 | INT64 | FLOAT | DOUBLE | BOOLEAN | TEXT
    ;

INT32: 'INT32';

INT64: 'INT64';

FLOAT: 'FLOAT';

DOUBLE: 'DOUBLE';

BOOLEAN: 'BOOLEAN';

TEXT: 'TEXT';

WS
    : [ \r\n\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

This is a listener. I wrote it casually, Please ignore the class name and other trivial things.

```java
package com.boris.sql;

import com.boris.sql.sqlParser.SingleStatementContext;

public class Hello extends sqlBaseListener {

  @Override
  public void enterSingleStatement(SingleStatementContext ctx) {
    super.enterSingleStatement(ctx);
    if (ctx.dataType().BOOLEAN() != null) {
      System.out.println(ctx.dataType().BOOLEAN().getText());
    }

    if (ctx.dataType().FLOAT() != null) {
      System.out.println(ctx.dataType().FLOAT().getText());
    }

    if(ctx.dataType().DOUBLE() != null) {
      System.out.println(ctx.dataType().DOUBLE().getText());
    }

    if(ctx.dataType().INT32() != null) {
      System.out.println(ctx.dataType().INT32().getText());
    }

    if(ctx.dataType().INT64() != null) {
      System.out.println(ctx.dataType().INT64().getText());
    }

    if(ctx.dataType().TEXT() != null) {
      System.out.println(ctx.dataType().TEXT().getText());
    }

  }
}
```

A driver program to run a simple example,

```java
package com.boris.sql;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class Driver {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String query = "CREATE TIMESERIES INT32";
    sqlLexer lexer = new sqlLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(query));
    CommonTokenStream tokns = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    sqlParser parser = new sqlParser(tokns);
    ParseTree tree = parser.singleStatement();
    ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
    walker.walk(new Hello(), tree);
  }
}
```

Yes, as you can see, I get the right result, "INT32". I know "enter" methods used to enter nodes and do something you want when traversing a tree. But I try to avoid using too many if clause. Do you have other ways to get the dataType?

---

sqlBaseListener class is generated by anltr4, you should know anltr4 to understand it.

Comment: Lookup Java Reflection in Google

Comment: @Tarik it's something about Java Reflection? it seems like an antlr problem.

Comment: The idea is to loop through all the methods such as DOUBLE and INT32 found through reflection, and invoke getText() for each. What do you mean by antlr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `getText()` no matter which type you have, so you don't need to actually check the type. You can just call always call `getText`. Since `dataType` consists entirely of a single token, you can just call `ctx.dataType().getText()` and you'll get the same result as in your current code.

If you wanted to treat the different alternatives differently without using `if`, you could name the alternatives and then define different `enter` methods for each type:

```
dataType
    : INT32 #TypeInt32
    | INT64 #TypeInt64
    | FloatType #Float
    ...
    ;
```

And then in the listener:

```
@Override
public void enterTypeInt32(TypeInt32Context ctx) {
    System.out.println("It's a 32-bit integer!");
}

@Override
public void enterTypeInt64(TypeInt64Context ctx) {
    System.out.println("It's a 64-bit integer!");
}

@Override
public void enterTypeFloat(TypeFloatContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("It's a single-precision float!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative. Change your rule to assign the matched token to a context member variable:

```
dataType
    : type = INT32
    | type = INT64
    | type = FLOAT
    | type = DOUBLE
    | type = BOOLEAN
    | type = TEXT
;
```

Then use this member in a switch statement for different handling:

```
  @Override
  public void enterDataType(DataTypeContext ctx) {
    switch (ctx.type.getType()) {
      case INT32:
        System.out.println("It's a 32-bit integer!");
        break;
      case INT64:
        System.out.println("It's a 64-bit integer!");
        break;
      ...
    }
  }
```

This is probably the simplest solution and easy to enhance later, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

"ctx.dataType().BOOLEAN()","ctx.dataType().FLOAT()"...returns different type of class ,you should create a parent class A ,use "ctx.dataType.A().getTxt()"，polymorphism. Then the different type of class instance assign to parent class A,avoid using too many if clause!!

Comment: Do you mean to add a member to the parser?

Comment: Just polymorphism,Class Parentclass = various kind of dataType, so in the if clause ctx.dataType() method you can return Parentclass instead of various kind of dataType.

Comment: You make it sound like OP has control over the code. Modifying the code generated by ANTLR is not a practical solution. Also: '"ctx.dataType().BOOLEAN()","ctx.dataType().FLOAT()"...returns different type of class' No, they don't. They all return tokens.